# Multi checkboxes in React that supply textareas when checked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs, checkbox

So I have started with a form that looks somewhat like this (using `reactstrap` as well):

```
<Form>
    <FormGroup check>
        <Label check>
            <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
            Work with customers for product/service feedback
        </Label>
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
        <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup check>
        <Label check>
            <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
            Get help with the research activity (build a survey, run experiments, analyze results, run usability or pilot studies, etc.)
        </Label>
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
        <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
    </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

As you can see, the form has checkboxes with the options and the idea is that if a checkbox is checked, then it should then show a textarea below it. That said, did some searching and ran across this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Container,
  Card,
  CardText,
  CardImg,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
    Button,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
    FormText,
    Col,
  Row } from 'reactstrap'
import Users from "./Users";


class ConnCust extends Component {

    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { checked: false };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    })
    }

    render() {
    const content = this.state.checked
      ? <div><Input type="textarea" placeholder="content1"></Input> Content </div>
            : null;

        const content2 = this.state.checked
        ? <div><Input type="textarea" placeholder="content2"></Input> Content 2 </div>
        : null;

    return <div>
      <div>
        <label>Check</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={ this.state.checked }
          onChange={ this.handleChange } />
      </div>

            <div>
        <label>Check</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={ this.state.checked }
          onChange={ this.handleChange } />
      </div>

            { content }
            { content2 }
        </div>;


  }
}

export default ConnCust;
```

So when one checkbox is checked, it selects both and shows the "content" for both. The idea is that I will have a dozen checkboxes, and for each one that a user selects, then it would accordingly show a `textarea` directly below that checkbox and label.

Not sure exactly where wrong here. Something to do with a `name` or `id` tag or how the `constructor` is setup?

Basically, the toggle is the checkbox. Can anyone assist with this?

UPDATE:

The scneario I am working within rather than a mock. Code looks like this"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Container,
  Card,
  CardText,
  CardImg,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
    Button,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
    FormText,
    Col,
  Row } from 'reactstrap'
import Users from "./Users";

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Form>
                <FormGroup check>
                    <Label check>
                        <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                        Work with customers for product/service feedback
                    </Label>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check>
                    <Label check>
                        <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                        Get help with the research activity (build a survey, run experiments, analyze results, run usability or pilot studies, etc.)
                    </Label>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check>
                    <Label check>
                        <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                        Validate new product/service ideas
                    </Label>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check>
                    <Label check>
                        <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                        Need assistance in Scheduling Customer Feedback meetings
                    </Label>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check>
                    <Label check>
                        <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                        Conduct Customer visit in person (Immerse)
                    </Label>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check>
                    <Label check>
                        <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                        Conduct customer visit remotely (Immerse)
                    </Label>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                </FormGroup>
                <Button><NavLink to="/Confirm">Submit</NavLink></Button>
            <Form>
        </Row>
        </Container>
    </div>
```

This scenario shows a `textarea` after each `checkbox` currently, but only the `textarea` should show if the option is selected.

Answer (score -1):

you can keep the array indicating the status of checkboxes, like this

```
state = {
checboxesStatus: new Array(10).map(() => false),
// lets say you have 10 checkboxes, you can use props, or set it after api //call, depends on you
}
Now in your render you can do something like this

    {this.state.checboxesStatus.map((element, index)=> {
      return (
        <div>
            <label>Check</label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={ this.state.checked }
              onChange={() => this.handleChange(index) } />
           {this.state.checboxesStatus[index] &&
          <Input type="textarea" placeholder="content2"></Input>
            }
          </div>

     )
     })}

handleChange = (index) => {
 const copychecboxesStatus = [...this.state.checboxesStatus]
 copychecboxesStatus[index] = !copychecboxesStatus[index]
this.setState({
checboxesStatus: copychecboxesStatus,
})

}
```

This way you can handle any number of checkboxes. Mind not tested the brackets. Please check it.

Comment: Kind of generic and not sure how to apply this as I haven't tried something quite like this in react. Can you or someone go a bit more in depth? How do I add each scenario for each individual question? Yes, the textarea would be the same, but the questions will differ.

Comment: I am not seeing how this would work since each checkbox has different info attached to it. With the array described here, the `handlechange` is simply copying info. Is that not correct? Look at some additional code I posted on the real scenario versus the mock I provided. This scenario shows a `textarea` after each `checkbox` currently, but only the `textarea` should show if the option is selected.